# WPF DataGrid SelectionChange event doesn't fire when ItemsSourse is being set from UserControl

Tags: wpf, datagrid, user-controls, selectionchanged

I have very interesting scenario here, look:

MainWindow XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TabControl Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged">
        <TabItem Header="First"/>
        <TabItem Header="Second"/>
    </TabControl>
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                      Content="{Binding SelectedUserControl}">

    </ContentPresenter>
</Grid>
```

UserControlOne XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
              ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" 
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" 
            Content="SetSource"
            Height="50"
            Command="{Binding SetSourceCommand}"/> 
    <Button Grid.Row="2" 
            Content="RemoveSource"
            Height="50"
            Command="{Binding RemoveSourceCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

UserContolTwo XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" 
                        Content="SetSource"
                        Height="50"
                        Command="{Binding SetSourceCommand}"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" 
                        Content="RemoveSource"
                        Command="{Binding RemoveSourceCommand}"
                        Height="50"/>
</Grid>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public class GridItem
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}


public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<GridItem> _items;
    private GridItem _selectedItem;
    private List<GridItem> _dataSource;
    private readonly List<UserControl> _userControlList;
    private UserControl _selectedUserControl;


    public UserControl SelectedUserControl
    {
        get { return _selectedUserControl; }
        set
        {
            _selectedUserControl = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedUserControl");
        }
    }


    public GridItem SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    public List<GridItem> DataSource
    {
        get { return _dataSource; }
        set
        {
            _dataSource = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("DataSource");
        }
    }

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        _items = new List<GridItem>
        {
            new GridItem { Name = "Igor" },
            new GridItem { Name = "Vasya"},
            new GridItem { Name = "Vladlen"}
        };

        _userControlList = new List<UserControl>
        {
            new UserControl1(),
            new UserControl2()
        };
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged

    private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedUserControl = _userControlList[((TabControl)sender).SelectedIndex];
    }


    #region SetSourceCommand

    private RelayCommand<Object> _setSourceCommand;
    public RelayCommand<Object> SetSourceCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _setSourceCommand ?? (_setSourceCommand =
                new RelayCommand<Object>(SetSourceMethod));
        }
    }

    private void SetSourceMethod(Object obj)
    {
        DataSource = _items;
        SelectedItem = _items.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    #endregion SetSourceCommand


    #region RemoveSourceCommand

    private RelayCommand<Object> _removeSourceCommand;
    public RelayCommand<Object> RemoveSourceCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _removeSourceCommand ?? (_removeSourceCommand =
                new RelayCommand<Object>(RemoveSourceMethod));
        }
    }

    private void RemoveSourceMethod(Object obj)
    {
        DataSource = null;
    }

    #endregion RemoveSourceCommand   


    #region SelectionChangedCommand

    private RelayCommand<Object> _selectionChangedCommand;
    public RelayCommand<Object> SelectionChangedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectionChangedCommand ?? (_selectionChangedCommand =
                new RelayCommand<Object>(SelectionChangedMethod));
        }
    }

    private void SelectionChangedMethod(Object obj)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Event have been rised! Selected item is {0}", ((DataGrid)obj).SelectedItem ?? "NULL");    
    }

    #endregion RemoveSourceCommand
}
```

I have `MainWindow`, that contains `UserControl`. `UserControl` is being set dinamically, so if you pick up `FirstTabItem`, then `UserControlOne` will be loaded and if you pick up `SecondTabItem` - `UserControlTwo` will be loaded into `ContentPresenter` of `MainWindow`.

If I click button `SetSource` on `FirstTabItem` (actually on `UserControlOne`) - then `SelectionChanged` event of `DataGrid` fires as usually. But if I click button `SetSource` on `SecondTabItem` (actually on `UserControlTwo`) - then `SelectionChanged` event of `DataGrid` doesn't fire at all. Despite on bouth buttons bound to the same command (`SetSourceCommand`).

If buttons don't placed on other controls, for example, only on different tabitems of the same `TabControl` - bouth buttons invokes `SelectionChange` event. So problem really in markup, in using `UserControls`.

Has anyone encoutered with that problem? How can I fix it? I don't want invoke eventhandler programmatically.

I posted all the required code here, so you can copy-paste it and try by yourself very quickly. Or I can load example project if someone interested.

Comment: Can you post the solution in zipped format?

Comment: @aks81, here [link](https://www.sendspace.com/file/i0dwkj)

Comment: Will try to get back with the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @aks81 no results or you have not tried yet?

Comment: Sorry yesterday I did not get time to try :(

Comment: Try using the `RelativeSource` `Binding` to point the `Command`. For example `Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=SetSourceCommand}"`.

Comment: @aks81, commands are working already, `DataSource` of grid is being updated, so it is not a problem. You will see it if you check project. I try your suggestion just for interest and commands became to be unworking (binding errors), so it is bad idea.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I debugged your code and found the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so here is the actual problem in your code.

The `UserControl1` has a grid in which you have used the `SelectedItem` Dependency Property. On this specific DP you have a `Command` `SelectionChangedCommand`.

In you commands `SetSourceCommand` and `RemoveSourceCommand` you are updating `SelectedItem` of the data grid which fires the `SelectionChangedCommand` because of the event `SelectionChanged`.

In your `UserControl2` there is no data grid nor any control which fires `SelectionChanged` event to call `SelectionChangedCommand`. Hence it is never executed.

Comment: It was clearly that event doesn't fire when current loaded `UserControl` doesn't have `DataGrid` and question was `How can I fix it?`. It seems like problem has no solution, is it? Btw, now I see that I was understand `SelectionChange` event of `DataGrid` completely wrongly. It fires when `Selection` changes, not `SelectedItem` changes. I think I can make my own `DataGrid` with `SelectedItemChanged` event.

Comment: the `SelectedItem` fires the `SelectionChanged` event internally. When ever the property `SelectedItem` changes whether from user interaction or programatically the `SelectionChanged` event will fire.

Comment: Just a vague idea. In your `UserControl2` why not define a DataGrid with `Visibility` to `Collapsed` which will not be visible on the UI but it will help in firing the `SelectionChangedCommand`

Comment: but as we've seen, `SelectionChanged` doesn't fire when `SelectedItem` property changed if `DataGrid` actually not shown.

Comment: That is because in your `UserControl2` there is not control which needs to handle the `SelectionChangedCommand`

Comment: You need to understand one point very clearly. The `SetCommand` or `RemoveCommand` is not responsible to fire the `SelectionChangedCommand`. The `SelectionChanged` event is responsible to fire it which is missing in `UserControl2`

Comment: But `DataGrid` instance is allocated in memory, and its `SelectedItem` property is changed but `SelectionChanged` event doesn't fire.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59327/discussion-between-aks81-and-monstr).

Comment: hi, I investigate the problem again and found that event `SelectionChanged` works perfectly. And in fact problem is that `Command` bound to `SelectionChanged` doesn't fire when event fires. If you interested - I waiting in yesterday's chat.

Comment: I have dropped messages for you. Just use the [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59327/discussion-between-aks81-and-monstr) and access the messages

Comment: I have dropped messages for you too